Orika mapper : Cannot register converters after MapperFacade has been initialized
I am getting this error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register converters after MapperFacade has been initialized" for my Oricka mapper. I am using spring framework(5.3.12) project with Java 17. I tried several solution but each resulted in same error as mentioned. I tried this Orika Mapper solution by making addConverter() as static function in below code but it didn't worked :
import ma.glasnost.orika.Converter;
import ma.glasnost.orika.Mapper;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class OrikaMapper extends ConfigurableMapper implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private MapperFactory factory;

    @Override
    protected void configureFactoryBuilder(final DefaultMapperFactory.Builder factoryBuilder) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final MapperFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory; 
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        addAllSpringBeans(applicationContext);
    }

    private void addAllSpringBeans(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final Map<String, Converter> converters = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Converter.class);
        for (final Converter converter : converters.values()) {
            addConverter(converter);
        }

        final Map<String, Mapper> mappers = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Mapper.class);
        for (final Mapper mapper : mappers.values()) {
            addMapper(mapper);
        }
    }

    public void addConverter(final Converter<?, ?> converter) {
        factory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(converter);
    }

    public void addMapper(final Mapper<?, ?> mapper) {
        factory.classMap(mapper.getAType(), mapper.getBType())
                .byDefault()
                .customize((Mapper) mapper)
                .register();
    }
}

Orika mapper dependency :
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Check this answer from a previous post:
Orika Mapper - Cannot register converters after MapperFacade has been initialized
It looks like you need to initialize in the static area of the JVM, something similar to this:
private static MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
static {
 mapperFactory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Converter.class););
}

